# Which .NET Frameworks better to use

Tags: .net, .net-framework-version

I made a class library that can be made either using .NET Framework 2 either .NET Framework 4 without making any change in code. Which one is better to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer using the latest and greatest version since it gives you many more opportunities for you to work with if you wish to extend your library.
I only use older versions if there are environmental limitations outside of my control e.g. not able to install the latest version on server etc...

Comment: Cant people use the class that was made using .net-2.0 on their .net-4.0 projects?

Comment: If they have the source they can compile it for whatever version they wish - as long as the source stays compatible with all versions

Comment: *the latest and greatest version since it gives you many more opportunities ... I only use older versions if there are environmental limitations* Yes, use the newest version! Like the .NET Framework 4.5! Unless you have to support Windows XP! Then that's an environment restriction on the newer version...